# Lemma 10, Section 4.2 of Hungerford’s Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation, modules, free-modules

> Let $R$ be a ring with identity, $I$ ($\neq R$) an ideal of $R$, $F$ a free $R$-module with basis $X$ and $\pi : F\to F/IF$ the canonical epimorphism. Then $F/IF$ is a free $R/I$ module with basis $\pi (X)$ and $|\pi (X)| = |X|$.
>
> Recall that $IF = \{\sum_{i=1}^n r_ia_i \mid r_i\in I, a_i \in F, n \in \Bbb{N}\}$ and that the action of $R/I$ on $F/ IF$ is given by $(r+I)(a+IF) = ra +IF$.
>
> **Proof:** ……… Finally if $x, x' \in X$ and $\pi (x) = \pi (x')$ in $F/IF$, then $(1_R+I)\pi (x)-(1_R+I)\pi (x’)=0$. If $x\neq x'$, the preceding argument implies that $1_R\in I$, which contradicts the fact that $I\neq R$. Therefore, $x = x'$ and the map $\pi: X \to  \pi (X)$ is a bijection, whence $|X|= |\pi(x)|$·

**Question:** I don’t get Author proof of $\pi|_X$ is injective. It seems like Author beforehand assuming injectivity. For context, preceding argument refer to $\pi (X)$ is linearly independent.

Following argument is not circular to prove $\pi|_X$ is injective: if $x\neq x’$ and $\pi(x)=\pi (x’) =x+IF=x’+IF$, then $x-x’\in IF$. So $x-x’=\sum_{i=1}^nr_ia_i$ where $r_i\in I$, $a_i\in F$ and $n\in \Bbb{N}$. Since each $a_i$ is linear combination of elements of $X$ and $I$ is an ideal, we have $$x-x’=\sum_{i=1}^nr_ia_i =\sum_{i=1}^m s_i b_i$$
where $s_i\in I$, $b_i\in X$ and $m\in \Bbb{N}$. By linear independence of $X$, $m=2$, $(s_1,b_1)=(1_R,x)$ and $(s_2,b_2)=(-1_R,x)$. That means $s_1=1_R\in I$. Thus we reach contradiction. Hence $x=x’$.

Comment: Yes, I think your proof (from "Following argument is not circular to prove..." to the end) is fine. The author's intention is that since $\pi(x)$ and $\pi(x')$ are linearly disjoint in $F/IF$, and $(1_R+I)\pi (x)-(1_R+I)\pi (x’)=0$, one must have $1_R+I=0$, i.e. $1\in I$, which is absurd since $I\ne R$.

Comment: @Asigan What do you by linearly disjoint? To use linear independence of $\pi (X)$, we must assume $\pi (x)\neq \pi (x’)$.

Comment: Ok, that is a bit tricky. Note that in the previous sentences, the writer said
"On the other hand, if $\sum_{i=1}^m (r_k+I)\pi(x_k)=0$ with $r_k\in R$ and *$x_1,\cdots,x_m$ distinct elements of $X$* $\cdots$, then $r_k+I=0+I$ in $R/I$". That is, $(\pi(x))_{x\in X}$ is already linear independent, instead of "$(\pi(x))_{x\in X}$, after removing repeating elements, is linear dependent" (Though rigorously speaking the latter is also correct). Therefore $\pi(x)$, $\pi(x')$ are linear dependent, a fortiori unequal.

Comment: @Asigan I think you meant to write “… after removing repeating elements, is linear independent” and “…former is also correct”. Tbh I don’t known mathematical meaning of fortiori. Imo Author should have done: let $\{y_1,…,y_m\}$ be distinct subset of $\pi (X)$. Then $\exists x_i\in X$ such that $\pi (x_i)=y_i$. To avoid using injectivity before proving injectivity. Because until that point, distinct element of $X$ can map to same element under $\pi$. No need to deal with repeating element explicitly.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to say "… after removing repeating elements, is linear independent"

Comment: First, "a fortiori" is an alternative way to say "therefore, obviously...". Next, please carefully go through the part of the proof beginning with "On the other hand ...". The writer actually proved: "*If $x_1,\cdots, x_m\in X$ are distinct, then $\pi(x_1),\cdots,\pi(x_m)$ are linearly independent.*"  (Unfinished)

Comment: Therefore, if $\pi(x)=\pi(x')$ where $x\ne x'$ and $x,x'\in X$, i.e. $(1+I)\pi(x)-(1+I)\pi(x')=0$ for distinct $x,x'$ in $X$,
then from linearly independence of $\pi(x)$, $\pi(x')$ (see the previous sentence in my comment "The writer actually proved"), we infer $1+I$ is the zero element in $R/I$, i.e. $1\in I$.

Comment: Your proof (from "Following argument is not circular to prove..." to the end) is fine. If you still do not catch the author's method, use your own proof.

Comment: @Asigan ohhh….. I got it now. Thank you for the clarification. Again I will say you to, transfer your comment into answer. Especially your sentence “*If $x_1,…,x_m\in X$ are distinct, then $\pi(x_1),…,\pi(x_m)$ are linearly independent*”. Because comments are temporary.